# Zipping 100's of files stored on S3

Tags: php, amazon-s3, aws-sdk, amazon-ec2, aws-php-sdk

We use S3 to store various media uploaded via our application such as images, documents etc. We work in the property software industry and as a means of exchanging data stored in our system with property portals a common exchange format between portals is the Rightmove BLM data feed specification. This is essentially a zip file containing a delimited text file and any associated media which is sent via FTP to each portal. However a bottleneck in the process is downloading the media from S3 for zipping. For example one single account on our system could have in the region of 1000 images/documents to the downloaded and zipped in preparation for transfer (each file has to be name in a particular format for that particular portal (unique number, sequence numbers etc). However downloading 1000 images/documents from S3 to an EC2 server in the same region via the PHP SDK takes some time (60+ seconds). When doing this for multiple accounts at the same time it puts considerable load on the server.

Is there an better/faster way to download files from S3 so they can be prepped and zipped on the EC2 instance?

Thanks.

Comment: If S3 is the bottleneck, have you checked to see if you are housing on sufficiently many partitions? That can be affected by your naming scheme for your [keys](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/amazon-s3-performance-tips-tricks-seattle-hiring-event/).

Comment: have you tried using the aws cli tools on an ec2 and seeing if that performs any faster than the php sdk?

Comment: @ShawnMehan - You could be onto something here as the first 3 segments of the object key are always the same. Be interesting to see what % of performance improvement on average could be made changing this.

Comment: @EdgeCaseBerg Haven't tried the cli but might do that.

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to aggregate the zip as the files are added. Meaning, instead of zipping the files all at once, use a Lambda function to add them to a zip file as they're added to or updated on the S3 bucket. Then, the zip would be available more-or-less on demand.

Comment: Unfortunately this isn't going to work. If a single account on our system is configured to upload data to multiple portals, each of these portals will have a unique identifier which has to be built into the filename of each of the media items in the zip file. The number of items can vary between generation to generation so the only way to do this is from scratch each time. It's an incredibly wasteful process but that's how these uploads work and we have to work within that :(